# Get the next value of a primary key field before it is created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to assign the value of the next ID to be created to a session variable before actually creating it.

I used the below code but `idd` always results in `0`.

```
T_Order objorder = new T_Order();

int id = ((int)Session["logged_in"]);
var date = DateTime.Now;

if (Session["Order"] == null)
{
    objorder.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    objorder.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    objorder.DeliveryDate = date.AddDays(10);
    objorder.User_ID = id;
    objorder.OrderStatus_ID = 1;
    objorder.OfferType_ID = 16;
    objorder.TypeOfOrder_ID = 2;
    context.T_Order.Add(objorder);
    Session["Order"] = objorder.ID;
}

int idd = (int)Session["Order"];
```

How can I get the correct answer?

Comment: Use an auto-incremented database key. Do not try and create one (unless its a `Guid`). If multiple users are creating an `Order` - it will all fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using an auto-incrementing identity field for your primary key. In which case, Entity Framework does not generate it's value until it is saved. Makes sense, how can you know what the value should be before you save it?

There's really no reason why you shouldn't save the entity at the point you create it, then assign your session variable. Holding onto it may cause you other issues like the entity becoming un-attached to the context